# Hartl Rails Tutorial Chapter 8 - Cannot logout of Sample_App. All rspec tests pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would be extremely thankful for any help identifying why I cannot log out of my sample app. 
* All of my rspec tests pass. 
* When I go to log out on my localserver click log out, I am not logged out, and the link does not change to Sign In (although a rspec test for this passes).

Here are the relevant tests from authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "AuthenticationPages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before {click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Email", with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title',   text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it {should_not have_link('Sign in',  href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link ('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def  new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Here is sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] =  user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !self.current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end   

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

Here is _header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
                    <% if signed_in? %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
                        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                            <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Account <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user) %></li>
                                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <%=  link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>    
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>        
                    <% else %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
                    <% end  %>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And finally, here is the model user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation 
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token 

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

Here is what my WEBrick server is saying:

```
Started DELETE "/signout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-19 10:58:53 -0400
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"qP1xAF4YXTaFmjeHxS5SgvUx+6+c6us5AL4jqgEBeqQ="}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-19 10:58:53 -0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 21.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
[2012-06-19 10:58:53] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-19 10:58:53 -0400
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (11ms)
[2012-06-19 10:58:53] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

In case it is some issue with the cookies here is what is happening when I check the cookies in the browser:

Checking the cookies:
1. I clear all cookies
2. go to localhost:3000.  I am still signed in as user 2. I check cookies and I have no remember_token for local host. i do have a cookie named "_sample_app_session"
3. click sign out. Nothing happens, still signed in.
4. enter /signin. log in as user 3
5. i now have a remember_token in cookies.
6. click sign out. still showing i am signed in the top nav.
7. I click profile to see that I am logged in as user 2 (via debug)
8. i check cookies and remember token is gone, i still have the _sample_app_session

Do you have any way I can test what might be causing this?  I am really trying to solve this so I can procede with the tutorial.

Comment: Please post your routes for sign_out and the params hash when you click sign_out.

Comment: Here is the route for signout:    match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

Comment: I am not sure what the params hash when you click signout would be?

Comment: Update:  I still could not get this to work on my local server, but when I pushed it live to heroku the problem was not there...

Comment: I still have this problem, both in local and heroku :/

Answer (score 5):

Oh I too was having the same problem. Even I was pulling my hair off for the same. Then one of my friend noticed the code and helped me out. 
The problem is that you just missed to add the remember token from RAILS CONSOLE. Just check the part above cucumber which is optional. You will notice the part to add tokens from rails console.

rails console

> > User.first.remember_token

=> nil

> > User.all.each { |user| user.save(validate: false) }
> >
> > User.first.remember_token

Comment: Man, I spent more then two hours to handle this problem ! Thank you very much for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to migrate the db after pushing to heroku. I had a similar problem and it was gone after I run:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```