# Michael Hartl: Chapter 8 - unable to sign out of sample app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

All my rspec test pass, yet I am unable to sign out of the sample app. When I click "Sign Out" under the Account tab in the header, the link does not change to Sign In but remains as if the user is still logged in.

I also tried to implement the solution from this (very) similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093240/hartl-rails-tutorial-chapter-8-cannot-logout-of-sample-app-all-rspec-tests-pa). However, even after adding the remember token in the rails console, the problem persists.

Here is sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Here is the sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !self.current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end
end
```

Here is the _header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

And here is the model user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
  before_create :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}    
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  after_validation { self.errors.messages.delete(:password_digest) }

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

     def create_remember_token
       self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
     end
end
```

Comment: Maybe the cookie isn't being deleted? Everything else looks fine. Try `puts`-ing the cookie value after you try deleting it to see if its nil and that the subsequent call to current_user returns nil

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this, too.  try this:

```
def sign_out
  #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948756/why-are-my-rspec-tests-failing-but-my-app-is-working?lq=1
  self.current_user = nil
  @current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
```

so check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948756/why-are-my-rspec-tests-failing-but-my-app-is-working?lq=1) (it's the one commented out in my code) and see if it helps.  Good luck!